# NLTK Brills methods equivalence from version 2 to 3.5

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to train a corpus based on the example provided in https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/pages/using-wikicorpus-nltk-to-build-a-spanish-part-of-speech-tagger However, this example uses NLTK 2 for the training with BillTraining and the following imports and uses:

```
from nltk.tag.brill import SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate
from nltk.tag.brill import ProximateTokensTemplate
from nltk.tag.brill import ProximateTagsRule
from nltk.tag.brill import ProximateWordsRule

ctx = [ # Context = surrounding words and tags.
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule,  (1, 1)),
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule,  (1, 2)),
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule,  (1, 3)),
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule,  (2, 2)),
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (0, 0)),
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (1, 1)),
    SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateWordsRule, (1, 2)),
    ProximateTokensTemplate(ProximateTagsRule, (-1, -1), (1, 1)),
]
```

I want to find equivalences to these in NLTK 3.5 specifically for (SymmetricProximateTokensTemplate, ProximateWordsRule, ProximateTagsRule) in http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/brill_trainer.html but after looking around for some time I haven't found any equivalence. Does any of you have had the same problem? My knowledge of the library is still in development (newbie here) so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: There's a major overhaul of the brill code from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/549